# Propertly not declared in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I get that error in the hyperledger composer playground:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAMDK.png)

That's my submit transaction code:

```
{
  "$class": "org.example.basic.CarTransaction",
  "car": "resource:org.example.basic.Car#1",
  "newOwner": "resource:org.example.basic.Person#2"
}
```

It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `newOwner` property in your event in your modal(cto) file.

You didn't provide your code, so your event should be like below(**example**)
:

```
event CarTransaferEvent {
  --> Car asset
  o String oldOwner
  o String newOwner
}
```

And now you can emit event whenever transaction occurs. You have to write the code for this in `logic.js`.